# Un-Distort raw images received from the Leap motion cameras

Tags: opencv, image-processing, shader, distortion, leap-motion

I've been working with the leap for a long time now. 2.1.+ SDK version allows us to access the cameras and get raw images. I want to use those images with OpenCV for square/circle detection and stuff... the problem is i can't get those images undistorted. i read the docs, but don't quite get what they mean. here's one thing i need to understand properly before going forward

```
        distortion_data_ = image.distortion();
        for (int d = 0; d < image.distortionWidth() * image.distortionHeight(); d += 2)
        {
            float dX = distortion_data_[d];
            float dY = distortion_data_[d + 1];
            if(!((dX < 0) || (dX > 1)) && !((dY < 0) || (dY > 1)))
            {
               //what do i do now to undistort the image?
            }
        }
        data = image.data();
        mat.put(0, 0, data);
        //Imgproc.Canny(mat, mat, 100, 200);
        //mat = findSquare(mat);
        ok.showImage(mat);
```

in the docs it says something like this "
The calibration map can be used to correct image distortion due to lens curvature and other imperfections. The map is a 64x64 grid of points. Each point consists of two 32-bit values....(the rest on the dev website)"

can someone explain this in detail please, OR OR, just post the java code to undistort the images give me an output MAT image so i may continue processing that (i'd still prefer a good explanation if possible)

Comment: What is the resolution of your camera image? Probably each point in the calibration map tells you what offset is used to move the pixel. Maybe you can use that to initialize another map to use cv::remap

Comment: @Micka the raw image's resolution is 640x240. 'The map is a 64x64 grid of points. Each point consists of two 32-bit values' 
[link](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/skeletal/java/devguide/Leap_Images.html#get-the-calibration-map)
check the link u can see the raw image i get, the page describes how to get around and undistort it, but i don't quite understand it :(

Comment: Will you be able to convert from c to java yourself? Its quite good explained in the documentation, i'll try to add an answer soon.

Comment: @Micka yes i will be able to convert the code.. Thanks a lot.. Ill be waiting for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example on how to do it without using OpenCV. The following seems to be faster than using the Leap::Image::warp() method (probably due to the additional function call overhead when using warp()):

```
float destinationWidth = 320;
float destinationHeight = 120;
unsigned char destination[(int)destinationWidth][(int)destinationHeight];

//define needed variables outside the inner loop
float calX, calY, weightX, weightY, dX1, dX2, dX3, dX4, dY1, dY2, dY3, dY4, dX, dY;
int x1, x2, y1, y2, denormalizedX, denormalizedY;
int x, y;

const unsigned char* raw = image.data();
const float* distortion_buffer = image.distortion();

//Local variables for values needed in loop
const int distortionWidth = image.distortionWidth();
const int width = image.width();
const int height = image.height();

for (x = 0; x < destinationWidth; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < destinationHeight; y++) {
        //Calculate the position in the calibration map (still with a fractional part)
        calX = 63 * x/destinationWidth;
        calY = 63 * y/destinationHeight;
        //Save the fractional part to use as the weight for interpolation
        weightX = calX - truncf(calX);
        weightY = calY - truncf(calY);

        //Get the x,y coordinates of the closest calibration map points to the target pixel
        x1 = calX; //Note truncation to int
        y1 = calY;
        x2 = x1 + 1;
        y2 = y1 + 1;

        //Look up the x and y values for the 4 calibration map points around the target
        // (x1, y1)  ..  .. .. (x2, y1)
        //    ..                 ..
        //    ..    (x, y)       ..
        //    ..                 ..
        // (x1, y2)  ..  .. .. (x2, y2)
        dX1 = distortion_buffer[x1 * 2 + y1 * distortionWidth];
        dX2 = distortion_buffer[x2 * 2 + y1 * distortionWidth];
        dX3 = distortion_buffer[x1 * 2 + y2 * distortionWidth];
        dX4 = distortion_buffer[x2 * 2 + y2 * distortionWidth];
        dY1 = distortion_buffer[x1 * 2 + y1 * distortionWidth + 1];
        dY2 = distortion_buffer[x2 * 2 + y1 * distortionWidth + 1];
        dY3 = distortion_buffer[x1 * 2 + y2 * distortionWidth + 1];
        dY4 = distortion_buffer[x2 * 2 + y2 * distortionWidth + 1];

        //Bilinear interpolation of the looked-up values:
        // X value
        dX = dX1 * (1 - weightX) * (1- weightY) + dX2 * weightX * (1 - weightY) + dX3 * (1 - weightX) * weightY + dX4 * weightX * weightY;

        // Y value
        dY = dY1 * (1 - weightX) * (1- weightY) + dY2 * weightX * (1 - weightY) + dY3 * (1 - weightX) * weightY + dY4 * weightX * weightY;

        // Reject points outside the range [0..1]
        if((dX >= 0) && (dX <= 1) && (dY >= 0) && (dY <= 1)) {
            //Denormalize from [0..1] to [0..width] or [0..height]
            denormalizedX = dX * width;
            denormalizedY = dY * height;

            //look up the brightness value for the target pixel
            destination[x][y] = raw[denormalizedX + denormalizedY * width];
        } else {
            destination[x][y] = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have no leap camera to test all this, but this is how I understand the documentation:

The calibration map does not hold offsets but full point positions. An entry says where the pixel has to be placed instead. Those values are mapped between 0 and 1, which means that you have to mutiply them by your real image width and height.

What isnt explained explicitly is, how you pixel positions are mapped to 64 x 64 positions of your calibration map. I assume that it's the same way: 640 pixels width are mapped to 64 pixels width and 240 pixels height are mapped to 64 pixels height.

So in general, to move from one of your 640 x 240 pixel positions (pX, pY) to the undistorted position you will:

1. compute corresponding pixel position in the calibration map: `float cX = pX/640.0f * 64.0f; float cY = pY/240.0f * 64.0f;`
2. (cX, cY) is now the locaion of that pixel in the calibration map. You will have to interpolate between two pixel locaions, but I will now only explain how to go on for a discrete location in the calibration map `(cX', cY') = rounded locations of (cX, cY)`.
3. read the x and y values out of the calibration map: dX, dY as in the documentation. You have to compute the location in the array by: `d = dY*calibrationMapWidth*2 + dX*2;`
4. dX and dY are values between 0 and 1 (if not: dont undistort this point because there is no undistortion available. To find out the pixel location in your real image, multiply by the image size: `uX = dX*640; uY = dY*240;`
5. set your pixel to the undistorted value: `undistortedImage(pX,pY) = distortedImage(uX,uY);`

but you dont have discrete point positions in your calibration map, so you have to interpolate. I'll give you an example:

let be (cX,cY) = (13.7, 10.4)

so you read from your calibration map four values:

1. calibMap(13,10) = (dX1, dY1)
2. calibMap(14,10) = (dX2, dY2)
3. calibMap(13,11) = (dX3, dY3)
4. calibMap(14,11) = (dX4, dY4)

now your undistorted pixel position for (13.7, 10.4) is (multiply each with 640 or 240 to get uX1, uY1, uX2, etc):

```
// interpolate in x direction first:
float tmpUX1 = uX1*0.3 + uX2*0.7
float tmpUY1 = uY1*0.3 + uY2*0.7

float tmpUX2 = uX3*0.3 + uX4*0.7
float tmpUY2 = uY3*0.3 + uY4*0.7

// now interpolate in y direction
float combinedX = tmpUX1*0.6 + tmpUX2*0.4
float combinedY = tmpUY1*0.6 + tmpUY2*0.4
```

and your undistorted point is:

`undistortedImage(pX,pY) = distortedImage(floor(combinedX+0.5),floor(combinedY+0.5));` or interpolate pixel values there too.

Hope this helps for a basic understanding. I'll try to add openCV remap code soon! The only point thats unclear for me is, whether the mapping between pX/Y and cX/Y is correct, cause thats not explicitly explained in the documentation.

Here is some code. You can skip the first part, where I am faking a distortion and creating the map, which is your initial state.

With openCV it is simple, just resize the calibration map to your image size and multiply all the values with your resolution. The nice thing is, that openCV performs the interpolation "automatically" while resizing.

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../Data/Lenna.png");

    cv::Mat distortedImage = input.clone();

    // now i fake some distortion:
    cv::Mat transformation = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64FC1);
    transformation.at<double>(0,0) = 2.0;
    cv::warpPerspective(input,distortedImage,transformation,input.size());



    cv::imshow("distortedImage", distortedImage);
    //cv::imwrite("../Data/LenaFakeDistorted.png", distortedImage);

    // now fake a calibration map corresponding to my faked distortion:
    const unsigned int cmWidth = 64;
    const unsigned int cmHeight = 64;

    // compute the calibration map by transforming image locations to values between 0 and 1 for legal positions.
    float calibMap[cmWidth*cmHeight*2];
    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < cmHeight; ++y)
        for(unsigned int x = 0; x < cmWidth; ++x)
        {
            float xx = (float)x/(float)cmWidth;
            xx = xx*2.0f; // this if from my fake distortion... this gives some values bigger than 1
            float yy = (float)y/(float)cmHeight;

            calibMap[y*cmWidth*2+ 2*x] = xx;
            calibMap[y*cmWidth*2+ 2*x+1] = yy;
        }


    // NOW you have the initial situation of your scenario: calibration map and distorted image...

    // compute the image locations of calibration map values:
    cv::Mat cMapMatX = cv::Mat(cmHeight, cmWidth, CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat cMapMatY = cv::Mat(cmHeight, cmWidth, CV_32FC1);
    for(int j=0; j<cmHeight; ++j)
        for(int i=0; i<cmWidth; ++i)
        {
            cMapMatX.at<float>(j,i) = calibMap[j*cmWidth*2 +2*i];
            cMapMatY.at<float>(j,i) = calibMap[j*cmWidth*2 +2*i+1];
        }

    //cv::imshow("mapX",cMapMatX);
    //cv::imshow("mapY",cMapMatY);


    // interpolate those values for each of your original images pixel:
    // here I use linear interpolation, you could use cubic or other interpolation too.
    cv::resize(cMapMatX, cMapMatX, distortedImage.size(), 0,0, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    cv::resize(cMapMatY, cMapMatY, distortedImage.size(), 0,0, CV_INTER_LINEAR);


    // now the calibration map has the size of your original image, but its values are still between 0 and 1 (for legal positions)
    // so scale to image size:
    cMapMatX = distortedImage.cols * cMapMatX;
    cMapMatY = distortedImage.rows * cMapMatY;


    // now create undistorted image:
    cv::Mat undistortedImage = cv::Mat(distortedImage.rows, distortedImage.cols, CV_8UC3);
    undistortedImage.setTo(cv::Vec3b(0,0,0));   // initialize black

    //cv::imshow("undistorted", undistortedImage);

    for(int j=0; j<undistortedImage.rows; ++j)
        for(int i=0; i<undistortedImage.cols; ++i)
        {
            cv::Point undistPosition;
            undistPosition.x =(cMapMatX.at<float>(j,i)); // this will round the position, maybe you want interpolation instead
            undistPosition.y =(cMapMatY.at<float>(j,i));

            if(undistPosition.x >= 0 && undistPosition.x < distortedImage.cols 
                && undistPosition.y >= 0 && undistPosition.y < distortedImage.rows)

            {
                undistortedImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = distortedImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(undistPosition);
            }

        }

    cv::imshow("undistorted", undistortedImage);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    //cv::imwrite("../Data/LenaFakeUndistorted.png", undistortedImage);
}


cv::Mat SelfDescriptorDistances(cv::Mat descr)
{
    cv::Mat selfDistances = cv::Mat::zeros(descr.rows,descr.rows, CV_64FC1);
    for(int keyptNr = 0; keyptNr < descr.rows; ++keyptNr)
    {
        for(int keyptNr2 = 0; keyptNr2 < descr.rows; ++keyptNr2)
        {
            double euclideanDistance = 0;
            for(int descrDim = 0; descrDim < descr.cols; ++descrDim)
            {
                double tmp = descr.at<float>(keyptNr,descrDim) - descr.at<float>(keyptNr2, descrDim);
                euclideanDistance += tmp*tmp;
            }

            euclideanDistance = sqrt(euclideanDistance);
            selfDistances.at<double>(keyptNr, keyptNr2) = euclideanDistance;
        }

    }
    return selfDistances;
}
```

I use this as input and fake a remap/distortion from which I compute my calib mat:

input:

[image]

faked distortion:

[image]

used the map to undistort the image:

[image]

TODO: after those computatons use a opencv map with those values to perform faster remapping.

Comment: Tried a lot on java.. Kinda getting a black screen but i assume it I'm doing it wrong. Will try it in c++ only and comment back.. Thanks a lot, this code made everything so clear, my concepts n stuff!

Comment: You are essentially correct about the calibration grid. One thing to note, though, is that the grid isn't directly tied to the 640x240 pixel size of the raw data -- you can use the same basic method for any size destination image (obviously there is a qualitative limit to how much you can blow up the image). In fact, the API was designed for use in a fragment shader where you wouldn't know the pixel size of the output.